# Trouble understanding SciPy.signal.spectrogram output

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I cannot seem to figure out what Sxx in SciPy's spectrogram function represents. It would make sense to me that summing a column of Sxx (summing the entire frequency band of a single time interval) would result in a value similar to the amplitude of that same time interval, but that does not seem to be the case. Can anyone help me better understand what the values mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the amplitude, but the energy, summed over a window of the same length as the FFT's.  Then use the squared magnitudes sum (minus any window scalloping losses).

See [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem).

Note than many (most?) spectrograms also convert the FFT results energy into decibels (dB) by taking the log10() of the FFT result magnitudes and then scaling to match the plot depth; so you may need to undo that to get the energy values.